# Is there an 'Open Folder...' keyboard shortcut in VS Code?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

I don't see a keyboard shortcut for "Open Folder..." listed on the documentation page below, and after searching elsewhere for a while I didn't see anything else.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings

I thought I would ask here before putting an issue on GitHub about it. (Also there doesn't seem to be a open / closed issue about this anywhere on the GitHub repo.)

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is indeed a shortcut for it, the command is `workbench.action.files.openFolder`, and the default keybinding is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.

It's easy to find in the list of shortcuts (*File → Preferences → Keyboard Shortcuts*) if you search for "folder" or "openFolder" in the Default Keybindings.

Answer (score 1):

Hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> on macOS or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> on Windows/Linux to activate the open dialog, select a folder, and click "Open."

Note: This answer was written before multiple folder workspaces were implemented in VS Code.  If you open folders this way, it will replace your entire workspace with the folder you selected to open.  If you want to add a folder to your existing workspace, you must use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> on a macOS or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> on Windows/Linux.

Comment: It's for file not for folder. @Gama11's solution works

Comment: @JanatbekSharsheyev it works for both by default.  If you select a folder it will still let you click "Open" then open the folder in VS Code.  However, it will replace your entire workspace with the new open folder.  You will need to use Gama11's solution only if you want to add a folder to your current workspace (which wasn't even a feature when I wrote this answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have to type Ctrl+K and then Ctrl+O to open a folder in Vs code on Windows and you have to type Cmd+K and Cmd+O to open folder in Vs code on mac...